# No Xcode support for iOS 12.3

Tags: ios, xcode

My phone has updated to iOS 12.3 beta, the latest Xcode 10.2 beta only supports up to iOS 12.2.

Is there a beta version of xcode anywhere that is compatible with iOS 12.3?

I guess the options are to wait for apple to release a new version of xcode or to roll back. unless anyone knows otherwise?

Comment: Please Check it. Its will helpfull in feature - https://stackoverflow.com/a/52815254/8526454

Comment: This is kind of a strange result but I found that if I just ran the program with 12.2 support it "just worked" even though the phone was running 12.3.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I find a solution to fix this problem.

You should make a folder named 12.3 (... what is written in your error message) in Program/Xcode-beta/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platforms/DeviceSupport/ and copy the files from 12.2 in there.

Now you can run your apps on iPhones with iOS 12.3.

Comment: 12.3 has bugs that affect Facebook login. Apple changed something :-|. This solution won't help us debug those bugs.

Comment: You misspelled "copy". I would have fixed it myself if I could.

Comment: It's a trick. It's actually iOS 12.2, so I don't think it helps to debug.

Comment: If anyone dont have iOS 12.2 Device support files - they can be found here [link](https://github.com/iGhibli/iOS-DeviceSupport/blob/master/DeviceSupport/12.2%20(16E226).zip)

Comment: @DawnSong please check out my answer. I believe thats what you're looking for. This accepted answer isn't correct if you want to debug in an iOS 12.3 environment.

Comment: You saved me a day bro!

Comment: Thank you! I was infuriated until I got this working, you saved me!

Comment: It's still freezes. With this solution you just removing warning. But speed of debug is sill awful, as and before this "trick".

Comment: If someone is not able to find the applications folder, right click on Xcode and click show package contents

Comment: I have this error but with version 12.4. I tried what your described but it's not working

Answer (score 3):

Any update on The IOS 12.3 Beta Developer Disk Image?
The official Debugging File for iOS 12.3 is not available.
You can try the following method to let Xcode support debugging iOS 12.3 devices.
1. Go to the folder /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport
2. Create a folder named "12.3".
3. Copy the "12.2" file to the "12.3" folder.

Answer (score 3):

How I fixed a similar issue with iOS 12.4

Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport and create folder called **12.4 (16G77)** and copy the files from one of the previous folders f.e 12.3

Go to Xcode and click on the "Set active scheme menu" and click on **Download Simulators** at the bottom:

[image]

Xcode will automatically start updating and re-creating the supporting files for 12.4:

[image]

Hope this will help someone.

Comment: Where can I find "Set active scheme menu"?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, Xcode 10.2.1 could debug with real devices running iOS 12.3

Try it by yourself.

Comment: That's not the question. He ask about the deployment target

Comment: copied and renamed to 12.3, but does not appear in Xcode10.2 > deployment Info> deployment target. It has some weird extension. THX for help

Comment: @hardworker The question is how to run your app into iOS 12.3, and deployment target is the minimal version of iOS your app supported.

Comment: @HiDuEi Try Xcode 10.2.1, instead of 10.2. If you set deployment target to 12.3, your app can only be run on iOS 12.3 or later. Is it really what you want?

Comment: @DawnSong how to run into IOS 12.3 globally, not with a real device only.

Comment: @hardworker Do you want to create simulators of iOS 12.3 for Apple?

Comment: @DawnSong I don't need, just have to read the marked answer of this question. Anyway, that's off topic, try to relax

Comment: @hardworker Ah, iSee. Which XcodeVersion for iOS 12.2 Development is good? 10.1., too? won´t use 10.2 if not necessary. THX!!

Answer (score 0):

worked for me:
1. cd /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport
2. cp 12.0 12.2
3. cp 12.0 12.3
4. downloaded Apple configurator and identified the connected devices
5. in xCode targeted the connected device
6. build worked

Answer (score 0):

How I fixed similar issue with **iOS 12.5.3** (XCode 10.1)

I opened Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport in Finder, created folder called ***12.5.3 (16H41)*** and copied the files from folder ***12.4 (16G77)***.