# Xcode 10.2 not building for ios 12.3 beta 1

Tags: xcode, ios12

I had update of iPhone to 12.3 beta 1. But apparently it throws error

```
 This iPhone 7 (Model 1660, 1778, 1779, 1780) is running iOS 12.3
 (16F5117h), which may not be supported by this version of Xcode.
```

in addition there is no any Xcode beta on Apple developer portal to download.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No Xcode support for iOS 12.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55471745/no-xcode-support-for-ios-12-3)